# How to extend the PixiJS v7 Container class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, pixi.js

I am trying to port a word game from Pixi.js version 6.5.9 to 7.2.3:

[image: word game screenshot]

In the game I use a custom class `Tile.js` to represent the yellow draggable letter tiles:

```
'use strict';

function Tile(letter, value) {
    PIXI.Container.call(this); // Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor _Container cannot be invoked without 'new'

    this.col = NaN;
    this.row = NaN;
    this.letter = letter;
    this.value = value;
    
    // is this tile being dragged?
    this.drag = false;

    this.graph = new PIXI.Graphics();
    this.addChild(this.graph);

    this.letterText = new PIXI.Text('', {fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 40, fill: 0x000000});
    this.letterText.anchor.set(0.5);
    this.addChild(this.letterText);

    this.indexText = new PIXI.Text('', {fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 20, fill: 0x000000});
    this.indexText.anchor.set(1);
    this.addChild(this.indexText);

    this.setLetter(letter);
    this.setValue(value);
}
```

The class extends the `PIXI.Container` class by using this code:

```
Tile.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Container.prototype);
Tile.prototype.constructor = Tile;
```

And then to implement dragging I have added the methods:

```
Tile.prototype.setIteractive = function(onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd) {
    this.eventMode = 'static'; // previously: this.interactive = true;
    this.buttonMode = true;

    // it is important to set hitArea, otherwise pointerdown will be called on wrong tiles
    this.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, Tile.WIDTH, Tile.HEIGHT);

    this.on('pointerdown', onDragStart)
        .on('pointermove', onDragMove)
        .on('pointerup', onDragEnd);
 };

Tile.prototype.startDragging = function() {
    this.drag = true;
    this.scale.x = 1.4;
    this.scale.y = 1.4;
    this.alpha = 0.9;
};

Tile.prototype.stopDragging = function() {
    this.drag = false;
    this.scale.x = 1;
    this.scale.y = 1;
    this.alpha = 1;
};
```

After upgrading from Pixi.js version 6.5.9 to 7.2.3 I get the following error in the Edge browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor _Container cannot be invoked without 'new'

[image: error message]

Has my way of extending the `Container` class been deprecated?

I have searched [at the Github](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/tree/dev/packages/display/src) trying to understand, how to extend classes in the PixiJS v7 properly... I have tried to understand how `Container` extends `DisplayObject`, but it is very different syntax (maybe because it is typescript?)...

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the suggestion by @domis86 and have rewritten my custom `Tile.js` class to have a [PIXI.Container](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html) member:

```
function Tile(letter, value) {
    var _col = NaN;
    var _row = NaN;
    var _letter = letter;
    var _value = value;
    
    // is this tile being dragged?
    var _drag = false;
    
    var _cont = new PIXI.Container();
    _cont.eventMode = 'static';
    _cont.buttonMode = true;
    // the following line does not work, is undefined
    _cont.tile = this;
    
    var _graph = new PIXI.Graphics();
    _cont.addChild(_graph);

    var _letterText = new PIXI.Text('', {fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 40, fill: 0x000000});
    _letterText.anchor.set(0.5);
    _cont.addChild(_letterText);

    var _indexText = new PIXI.Text('', {fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 20, fill: 0x000000});
    _indexText.anchor.set(1);
    _cont.addChild(_indexText);

    setLetter(letter);
    setValue(value);
    
    function getContainer() {
        return _cont;
    }

    function setIteractive(onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd) {
        _cont.eventMode = 'static';
        _cont.buttonMode = true;
        setDrawSides(true, true, true, true);

        // it is important to set hitArea, otherwise pointerdown will be called on wrong tiles
        _cont.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        _cont.on('pointerdown', onDragStart)
            .on('pointermove', onDragMove)
            .on('pointerup', onDragEnd);
     }

    function startDragging() {
        _drag = true;
        _cont.scale.x = 1.4;
        _cont.scale.y = 1.4;
        _cont.alpha = 0.9;
        redraw();
    }

    function stopDragging() {
        _drag = false;
        _cont.scale.x = 1;
        _cont.scale.y = 1;
        _cont.alpha = 1;
        redraw();
    }

    ...more methods here...

    // return the public methods
    return {
        getContainer: getContainer,
        setIteractive: setIteractive,
        startDragging: startDragging,
        stopDragging: stopDragging,
        ...
        redraw: redraw
    };
}
```

The problem is, when a `Tile` instance is being dragged, then the `pointerdown` and other events are now called on the `_cont` and not on the `Tile` instance itself - and then I do not know how to access the additional properties (like `_letter`, `_value`, `_col`, `_row`) of the letter tile:

```
function onDragStart(ev) {
    this.data = ev.data;
    var pos = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
    this.x = pos.x - this.width / 2;
    this.y = pos.y - this.height / 2;
    // put the tile on top
    app.stage.removeChild(this);
    app.stage.addChild(this);
    // the following line gives error because PIXI.Container does not have the method
    this.startDragging();
    // here I only have access to the _cont through "this"
    // but how to access the _letter, _value of the tile?
}
```

I have tried adding a `.tile` property to the `_cont` by:

```
_cont.tile = this;
```

but it gives me `undefined` when I try to access `this.tile` in `onDragStart`

**UPDATE 2:**

The [PixiJS Elementals](https://www.pixijselementals.com/#getting-interactive) tutorial mentions that there is a way to pass a custom object (which would be the `Tile` instance in my case) to mouse events:

> The basic anatomy of adding an event listener to an imput is:
> yourObject.on("stringOfWhatYouWantToKnow", functionToBeCalled, contextForTheFunction)

but how to add it to my code, since `this` seems to be undefined and how to read it in the `onStartDrag()`etc.?

Comment: I think you should try using ES6 classes instead of "the old fashioned way".

Comment: What user @vr. above said. But i would advice to try to not extending Pixi Container class (and other Pixi classes). IMO Pixi classes should be used only for purposes that they are designed for, and they should be organized by higher level classes created by programmer. In your example i would create `Tile` class which contains following properties: `pixiContainer`, `col`, `row`, `letter`, `value`, `drag`. Then create also methods related to drawing, interaction, dragging etc in `Tile`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @domis86 but how to get access to the parent `Tile` instance, when the `PIXI.Container` is being dragged by mouse? Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/k1qr5m8g/

( is modified example from user bigtimebuddy from question "what's suggested way of implementing dragging in v7?" - https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/8813#discussioncomment-4038065 )

Please run it and observe the browser console. You should see something like this after clicking on rectangle (sprite):

```
called Tile.getMyValue() - value: 123
dumping "this":
Object { iAmTile: true }
```

> The PixiJS Elementals tutorial mentions that there is a way to pass a custom object (which would be the Tile instance in my case) to mouse events:

Notice this code fragment:

```
// Here we are passing the "that" (aka: original "this" of Tile object instance) as third argument.
// It will cause "this" inside getMyValue function to point to the Tile instance.
sprite.on('pointerdown', getMyValue, that);
```

Btw 1: I would recommend to convert your code to ES6 class - so as is done in https://www.pixijselementals.com/#getting-interactive

Btw 2: in your code do you create instances of Tile objects using "new" keyword? See at end of jsfiddle:

```
var tileInstance = new Tile('A', 123, app);
tileInstance.initializeInteractiveListeners();
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! If I remove `new` from the last lines of your fiddle, then it seems to work too. What is the difference? And why do you have save `this` to `that`, does the former value change?

Comment: `And why do you have save this to that, does the former value change?` - try passing "this" and observe console after click - you should see difference.

Comment: `If I remove new from the last lines of your fiddle, then it seems to work too` - without `new` it will not work correctly - you should see different thing in console after the `dumping "this":` on click (the "this" context will be global "window"). Please read this document - especially point 3 in part "Description" (is about "this" context) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description